# Conditional Validation with react-hook-form and yup for a radio button

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hook-form, yup

I try to add `yup` validation to my form which is built with `react-hook-form`. I also use the standard components from `@headlessui` to build my components. My usecase is the following:
If the `Radio Input` is checked with `"Yes"` the `Text Input` should be `required`, otherwise the `Text Input` is `optional`.

[image]

For some reason I can't add conditional validation to my `radio button` component. Maybe it has something todo with the `Controller` Component of `react-hook-form`.

I get the following error message:

```
  Overload 1 of 4, '(keys: string | string[], builder: ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>): StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ is: string; then: yup.StringSchema<string, yup.AnyObject, undefined, "">; otherwise: yup.StringSchema<string | undefined, yup.AnyObject, undefined, "">; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'is' does not exist in type 'ConditionBuilder<StringSchema<string | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'.typescript(2769)
```

This is my `TestForm` component and here is also a codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nice-framework-vkx7k5?file=%2Fcomponents%2Fform%2FTest%2FTestForm.tsx%3A46%2C17

```jsx
"use client";

import * as yup from "yup";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import InputField from "../../ui/InputField";
import RadioGroupInput from "../../ui/RadioGroupInput";
import { useFormState } from "./TestFormContext";

const validationSchema = yup.object({
  radioButtons: yup.string().required("Needed"),
  textInput: yup.string().when("radioButtons", {
    is: "Yes",
    then: yup.string().required("Needed"),
    otherwise: yup.string(),
  }),
});

export type FirstPageFormData = yup.InferType<typeof validationSchema>;

export default function TestForm() {
  const { setFormData, formData } = useFormState();

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting, isLoading },
    control,
    getValues,
    watch,
  } = useForm<FirstPageFormData>({
    defaultValues: formData,
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    shouldFocusError: false,
  });

  const watchAllFields = watch();

  async function onSubmit(data: FirstPageFormData) {
    setFormData((formData) => ({ ...formData, ...data }));
    alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="bg-white mt-6 px-4 py-5 shadow sm:rounded-lg sm:p-6">
          <div className="col-span-6">
            <Controller
              name="radioButtons"
              control={control}
              rules={{
                required: true,
              }}
              render={({ field }) => (
                <RadioGroupInput
                  label="Radio Buttons"
                  type="ghost"
                  error={errors.radioButtons}
                  radioButtons={[
                    {
                      title: "Yes",
                    },
                    {
                      title: "No",
                    },
                  ]}
                  field={field}
                />
              )}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
            <InputField
              id="textInput"
              name="textInput"
              type="text"
              label="Text Input"
              register={register("textInput")}
              error={errors.textInput}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-4 flex justify-end gap-4">
          <input
            type="submit"
            className="bg-gray-900 text-white p-2 rounded-md flex w-28 justify-center cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-700"
            disabled={isLoading}
            value="Submit"
          />
        </div>
      </form>
      <div>{JSON.stringify(watchAllFields)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to use `yup` with the following format

```jsx
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  radioButtons: yup.string().required("Needed"),
  textInput: yup.string().when("radioButtons", {
    is: "Yes",
    then: yup.string().required("Needed"),
    otherwise: yup.string(),
  }),
});
```

and also in this format

```jsx
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  radioButtons: yup.string().required("Needed"),
  textInput: yup.string().when("radioButtons", (val, schema) => {
    if (val === "Yes") return yup.string().required();
    else return yup.string().notRequired();
  }),
});
```

but I ended up with the error I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the schema to this and it works. They might have updated how the `.when` stuff works

```
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  radioButtons: yup.string().required("Needed"),
  textInput: yup.string().when('radioButtons', {
    is: 'Yes',
    then: (schema) => schema.required("Needed"),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema, // technically this otherwise isnt needed
  }),
});
```

Comment: I marked this answer as the "accepted answer", because I think the syntax is a little clearer then the solution of @yaman-abd, but both fixed my problem! Thanks also to Matt.

Answer (score 1):

what version of `yup` are you using in your project?

I had the same error with `"yup": "^1.2.0"`
also in another project I am using an older version which is:
`"yup": "^0.32.11"` and I used the same approach you used and worked fine without any issues.

however, this should work without any errors:

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    radioButtons: yup.string().required("Needed"),
    textInput: yup
      .string()
      .when("radioButtons", ([radioButtons], schema) =>
        radioButtons === "yes" ? schema.required("Needed") : schema.nullable().notRequired()
      )
  });
```

Comment: I also use the version "^1.2.0". Your solution works great! Thank you!